# Errors not showing against custom fields using hook validateForm()

Tags: hooks, validation, errorhandling

Using this code

if ($fields["custom_111_79"] == 0) $errors["custom_111_79"] = "Please enter number of physio sessions";

The evaluation is done correctly, but the error message does not appear against the custom field, but instead as a general error message top right of the screen.

This is in civi_case.

Is this supposed to work?
Is there another way of making custom fields work like normal fields?

Comment: The "79" is going to change for different records, and on a new form will be "-1". Also try it with just custom_111 when you set $errors.

Comment: Yes, aware of the changing suffix, and removing it makes no difference.